# PyQt5: Check if mouse is held down in enter-event

Tags: python, pyqt, mouseevent, pyqt5, mouse-buttons

My actual application is much more complicated than this, but the example below sums up the majority of my problem.  I have multiple QLabels that I've subclassed to make them clickable.  The labels display 16x16 images which requires a process of loading the images via Pillow, converting them to ImageQt objects, and then setting the pixmap of the label.  In the example, I have 3 clickable QLabels that run the print_something function each time I click on them.  My goal is to be able to hold the mouse down, and for each label I hover over, the function gets called. Any pointers would be great.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
import sys


class ClickableLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        if app.mouseButtons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.clicked.emit()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        self.setFixedSize(300, 300)
        image = Image.open("16x16image.png")
        image_imageqt = ImageQt(image)

        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.setSpacing(0)
        hbox.addStretch()

        label01 = ClickableLabel()
        label01.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image_imageqt))
        label01.clicked.connect(self.print_something)
        hbox.addWidget(label01)

        label02 = ClickableLabel()
        label02.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image_imageqt))
        label02.clicked.connect(self.print_something)
        hbox.addWidget(label02)

        label03 = ClickableLabel()
        label03.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image_imageqt))
        label03.clicked.connect(self.print_something)
        hbox.addWidget(label03)

        hbox.addStretch()

        central_widget.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def print_something(self):
        print("Printing something..")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I tried a combination of checking the mouseButtons and the enterEvent but when the mouse is held down, it seems to hold all other events until the button is let go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of the problem is stated in the docs for [QMouseEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html):

> Qt automatically grabs the mouse when a mouse button is pressed inside
>   a widget; the widget will continue to receive mouse events until the
>   last mouse button is released.

It does not look like there is a simple way around this, so something hackish will be required. One idea is to initiate a fake drag and then use `dragEnterEvent` instead of `enterEvent`. Something like this should probably work:

```
class ClickableLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.dragstart = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.dragstart = event.pos()
            self.clicked.emit()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.dragstart = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if (self.dragstart is not None and
            event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton and
            (event.pos() - self.dragstart).manhattanLength() >
             QtWidgets.qApp.startDragDistance()):
            self.dragstart = None
            drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
            drag.setMimeData(QtCore.QMimeData())
            drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.LinkAction)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.acceptProposedAction()
        if event.source() is not self:
            self.clicked.emit()
```

Comment: This works for what I was trying to accomplish, but now I need to figure out how to prevent the mouse cursor from changing during the drag-drop process

Comment: @huntrvro. I thought I'd done that by using `Qt.LinkAction`. It works for me on linux, but obviously not on other platforms. You can try to use [QDrag.setDragCursor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdrag.html#setDragCursor). The pixmaps for system cursors can be created using [QCursor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcursor.html).